# Distance calculation for coordinates called from a file(Python2.7)

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, type-conversion, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to read coordinates from a file and find distance between each two respective atoms in the file.
I want to have the calculated distance  in one column and the respective atom names in the other.

```
1 Br1 0 Br x,y,z 1.195 7.005 10.004
2 Br2 0 Br x,y,z 1.432 5.040 6.816
3 Br3 0 Br x,y,z -0.407 8.433 6.863
4 Br4 0 Br x,y,z 3.344 8.375 7.107
5 Fe1 0 Fe x,y,z 1.412 7.214 7.682
6 Br5 0 Br x,y,z 2.813 12.506 12.949
7 Br6 0 Br x,y,z 4.778 14.123 10.091
8 Br7 0 Br x,y,z 6.563 12.765 13.175
9 Br8 0 Br x,y,z 4.387 15.965 13.344
```

For instance:

```
Br1-Br2 1.5
```

I encounter two problems:

1-I have no idea how to command the program to calculate euclidean distance between each two pairs of atoms, I used split() to split coordinates from other data, but I still don't know how to calculate the distance.I found some info about the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645439/calculating-the-distance-between-atomic-coordinates), but the answers didn't work for me as they were for perl.

```
atom_positions= open('Atoms.txt','r')
revised_atom_positions = open('Atoms_atoms.txt','w')
aline = atom_positions.readline()#for getting rid of the first line data which is general info

for aline in atom_positions:
     Values = aline.split()
     dataline = values[1]+' , '+ values[5] + ' , ' + values[6] +' , '+values[7]
     revised_atom_positions.write(dataline + '\n')


atom_positions.close()
revised_atom_positions.close()
```

When I try to change it into an array and use pdist I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

2- I can store my new data in another file with new order, But i have no idea how to call them for distance calculations! there were some guidelines about `pdist` but it didn't work for me either.

are there any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index:

```
atom_positions= open('Atoms.txt','r')
revised_atom_positions = open('Atoms_atoms.txt','w')

lines = atom_positions.readlines()

for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    values = line.split()
    dataline = values[1]+' , '+ values[5] + ' , ' + values[6] +' , '+values[7]
    # You can access to next line with lines[i + 1]
    revised_atom_positions.write(dataline + '\n')


atom_positions.close()
revised_atom_positions.close()
```